# Bootstrap 3 doesn't resize on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Here there is an example of my problem:
http://asdcastelli.altervista.org/test-bootstrap/

In the head i have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

but the responsive works only if i resize the window browser, not in mobile

Why?
This is the page in the resized windows browser
[image]

This is the page in the mobile view (chrome inspector)
[image]

Comment: Is your `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` line the first line after the opening `<head>` tag?

Comment: This is the three first lines
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

You have to include table into a div.

```
<div class="responsive_table">
    <table id="pubblicazioni_table">
        /*your content*/
    </table>
</div>
```

and on your css, you have to paste this line:

```
.responsive_table { overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%;  }
```